# Determine the sample size.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, sampling

> An advertising agency that serves a major radio station would like to
>   estimate the average amount of time that the station’s audience spends
>   listening to radio on a daily basis. What sample size is needed if the
>   agency wants to be 90% confident of being correct to within +/- 5
>   minutes? From past studies, the standard deviation is estimated at 45
>   minutes.

I do not even know how to start. Any hit will be appreciate!

Comment: A 90% confidence interval corresponds to a z-score of 1.645.  the margin of error (5 minutes) will be equal to 1.645 times the sd of the mean of the colleted sample, which is equal to 45 divided by sqrt(N).  so 5 = 1.645*45/sqrt(N); or sqrt(N) = 1.645*45/5 = 14.81.  squaring gives, N= 219.2, so you would need to have a sample size of at least 220 to be 90% confident that the error in the sample average will be less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the distribution is normal.

Let $\sigma$ your standard deviation, $n$ the sample size, and $\mathrm{ME}$ your (semi-)margin of error. Then you just need
$$
z_{95\%} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \le \mathrm{ME}.
$$
Therefore
$$
N\ge \left\lceil \left(\frac{z_{95\%} \sigma}{\mathrm{ME}}\right)^2\right\rceil
$$

Comment: Your "formula" is upside down!  N >= (z*sig/ME)^2

Comment: 90% is in the middle, 5% at the right, 5% at the left. Hence you want that point on the standard normal which leaves you 95% at the left.

Comment: @PaoloLeoneti, why? Can you be more detailed, I do not see why I need 95%.

Comment: Because the confidence interval expresses you, informally, the "probability" (in truth, this is just $0$ or $1$) of being *inside* your interval. But your interval is centered, so you are not considering the left tail when you use the numbers $z_\alpha$.